# Java - How to dynamically name object based on parameters upon instantiation?

Tags: java, oop, instantiation

I'm trying to create a basic "addPlayer" method for a game. The method should add a "Player" to the array of players.

Current code:

```
  @Override
  public void addNewPlayer(String name) {
  Player one = new Player(name);
  players.add(one);
  }
```

The problem I have is that this can only create one Player, as the creation of the second will cause the second player to be associated with the name "one".

Ideally I'd like to make the name of the Player object dependant on the parameter "name" passed in. Is this possible?

I'm using Player objects to have a name and **int final identification** for the game. Maybe I need to rethink that design?

Comment: The name of the ```Player``` variable doesn't matter, you should just call that ```player```. Everytime you need to add a new player, you invoke ```addNewPlayer```. So the caller is the one that'll be doing the multiple calls to this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused. In your example `one` is only visible in the method scope, when the method ends that reference variable is no-longer reachable. You could change

```
public void addNewPlayer(String name) {
  Player one = new Player(name);
  players.add(one);
}
```

to

```
public void addNewPlayer(String name) {
  players.add(new Player(name));
}
```

Note that this is functionally identical to your version. `players` (assuming it's a `Collection`), can contain multiple `Player` instances.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the clarification! I was clearly confused and searching didn't help solve the question as it ended up being a non-issue.